# How to increase the partition size of Ubuntu 14.04 installed under Windows 7?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, disk

I have `windows 7` as primary OS. In past year I installed `Ubuntu 14.04` from live USB. I don't use `Wubi`. Now I have to increase the partition `/dev/sda6` size of Ubuntu.

```
user:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda6        16G   15G  275M  99% /
none            4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            3,9G  4,0K  3,9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           785M  1,2M  784M   1% /run
none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none            3,9G  372K  3,9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   44K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sdb1       279G  215G   64G  78% /media/user/035F3F68B14AD251
```

Update.

```
denis@denis:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 840 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  230GB  230GB   primary   ntfs            boot
 2      230GB   256GB  25,6GB  extended
 6      230GB   248GB  17,2GB  logical   ext4
 5      248GB   256GB  8445MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)


Model: ATA Hitachi HTS54503 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 2      32,3kB  21,6GB  21,6GB  primary  ntfs
 1      21,6GB  320GB   299GB   primary  ntfs         boot
```

And:

```
denis@denis:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 238,5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 214,6G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   7,9G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda6   8:6    0    16G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 298,1G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   278G  0 part /media/denis/035F3F68B14AD251
└─sdb2   8:18   0  20,1G  0 part
```

Comment: Add the output of `sudo parted -l` and `lsblk` as well, please.

Comment: @muru, I have done.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, may be that way will be work fine. But it sounds so complicated. I have to 1) download ubuntu iso; 2) make live usb; 3) perform set actions. Is there more simple way to complete my task?

Comment: "installed under Windows 7?"  explain that with "no wubi" please?

Comment: @Rinzwind, when I installed `Ubuntu`, installer said to me: "You have Windows, let I install Ubuntu near with your Windows".  I think, that it is not `wubi`, but I may be wrong.

Comment: That is not "under".

Comment: @Rinzwind, how correctly to say?

Comment: You can not resize your ubuntu partition when you are using (booted into) it or from windows. So a live usb is the only option.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, it sounds sad. But, thank you for information.

Answer (score 0):

First install `Gparted` if you have not already by:

`sudo apt-get install gparted`

and resize your 230GB windows partition (NTFS) to make unallocated space (you can decide the size of this partition). Do not make any changes to Ubuntu partition while you are logged into Ubuntu.

If you have live CD or USB with ubuntu boot from this and run `Gparted` from there. Now, merged this unallocated space to Ubuntu.

Also, just in case make sure you have make a copy of [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and use it in case this procedure messes up GRUB (there won't be a problem generally, but who knows!)

Comment: Generally speaking it is better to resize you windows partitions from within windows rather then a live usb or from Ubuntu. Doing so prevents a number of problems wiht windows. Often you have to defragment the windows partiton from windows first.